# Apache HttpComponents 5: POST form data with HttpAsyncClient

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-httpcomponents

I am looking for a solution to POST form data with `HttpAsyncClient`. All [examples](https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/tree/5.0.x/httpclient5/src/test/java/org/apache/hc/client5/http/examples) I've found so far only sent simple GET requests. This is what I've got so far:

```
try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault()) {
  SimpleHttpRequest httpPost = SimpleHttpRequests.post("http://httpbin.org");
  // How to add key=value as form data to httpPost?
  Future<SimpleHttpResponse> future = client.execute(httpPost, new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(SimpleHttpResponse simpleHttpResponse) {
      System.out.println(simpleHttpResponse.getCode());
      System.out.println(simpleHttpResponse.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {
      System.out.println("cancelled");
    }
  }
}
```

I also looked around the source code, where I found the `SimpleHttpRequest::setBody` method and the corresponding `SimpleBody` class. But they seem, too, not support form data.

Basically, I need the equivalent of `OkHttp`'s `FormBody`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some digging through the documentation and source code of Apache HttpComponents 5, I came up with the following solution. Instead of using `SimpleHttpRequests`, I need to create an `AsyncRequestProducer` and an `AsyncResponseConsumer`. The request producer object defines how to create my request and in contrast to the `SimpleHttpRequest`, it is able to also produce the form body that I need. Example code:

```
try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault()) {
  client.start();
  AsyncRequestProducer producer = AsyncRequestBuilder.post()
          .setUri("http://httpbin.org")
          .addParameter("key", "value") // <- form parameters in body
          .build();
  AsyncResponseConsumer<SimpleHttpResponse> consumer = SimpleResponseConsumer.create();
  client.execute(producer, consumer, new FutureCallback<SimpleHttpResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void completed(SimpleHttpResponse simpleHttpResponse) {
      System.out.println(simpleHttpResponse.getCode());
      System.out.println(simpleHttpResponse.getBody());
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelled() {
      System.out.println("cancelled");
    }
  });
}
```

Alternatively, I could use an `AsyncEntityProducer` to produce the form body:

```
Iterable<NameValuePair> params = Stream.of(new BasicNameValuePair("key", "value"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
AsyncEntityProducer entityProducer = AsyncEntityProducers.createUrlEncoded(params, Charsets.UTF_8);
AsyncRequestProducer producer = AsyncRequestBuilder.post()
        .setUri("http://httpbin.org")
        .setEntity(entityProducer)
        .build();
```

Comment: Note: The second alternative seems to be more stable for long strings. When using the first alternative, I get occasional HTTP 500 errors from the target web service when sending long strings.